# Simplify Embeded Password Reset Azure B2C Custom Policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I need to use custom policies to create authentication and password reset flow for my project.
I started using the [Azure B2C embedded password reset](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset). For the password reset flow, here is the result
[image]

Is it possible to either :

- remove the third step as show in the below picture. The email is still verified but the user does not need to know about it.
  [image]
- or to automate the transition between step 2 and 4 using javascript. In this scenario, how do I know on which screen I am to trigger the javascript allowing this automation. Can I get the "claim" from javascript code ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I used the solution suggested by @Jas Suri, but the third step is still showed for a second then go to the 4th one. Did you have the same behavior please?

Comment: To prevent at most  this behavior, I totally hide the body of the HTML dom to get a blank page. 
Something like document.body.display= none

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript mutator function. Use it to detect that the Continue button has changed property (become enabled), and then trigger a function to hide the Change button and perform a click event on the Continue button.

Answer (score 3):

Looking over your question and the options you've selected for reducing the steps in the Password Reset flow looks a lot like what I solved over here.  The `TechnicalProfile`s and the like involved were used as is from samples so I've included the JS I used and an explanation of what it eliminated.

Fixing this was more challenging than I expected or encountered with other JS customizations.  As the selected answer suggests, each step in the process does not guarantee a page load occurs and the buttons are re-used throughout steps so you can't just hide the ones that "are pointless" because they aren't pointless in future steps.  The most reliable way I could find was to monitor the `aria-hidden` attribute and alter the page at that point.

I'm using a custom `ContentDefinition` with the DataUri set to `urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.8` but it would likely work with previous page versions as long as the IDs remained the same as 2.1.8 -- I'm not using jQuery, but I'm using browser APIs that are not available in older browsers.

I have a helper function that creates the `aria-hidden` observer:

```js
    const createObserver = (name, onVisible, onHidden) => {
      let MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver

      let elem = document.getElementById(name)

      if (!!(elem)) {
        let observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
          mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            if (mutation.type == "attributes") {
              if (mutation.target.getAttribute('aria-hidden') == "true") {
                if (!!onHidden) {
                  onHidden()
                }
              } else {
                onVisible()
              }
            }
          });
        });
        observer.observe(elem, { attributes: true, attributeFilter: ['aria-hidden'] });
        return observer;
      }
      return undefined;
    }
```

Then I subscribe to it for a few fields in order to tweak the page:

```js
    const inputEmailObserver = createObserver('email_intro', () => {
      document.getElementById('continue').style.display = "none";
    });
    const verifyCodeObserver = createObserver('email_info', () => {
      document.getElementById('continue').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('email').disabled = true;
    });

    const verificationSuccessObserver = createObserver('emailVerificationControl_but_change_claims', () => {
      document.getElementById('continue').style.display = "inline";

      // There's a pointless page that shows up after you've verified your e-mail
      //   so to avoid the confusion, continue is clicked for the user, taking them
      //   to the password reset page
      document.getElementById('continue').click();
    });
```

The changes center around the behavior of the `Continue` button.  It doesn't really have a reason to exist the way we wanted the flow to work (I can't see a use for it *most* of the time, but I could be missing something).  The only time it doesn't return an error message, its purpose is to take the user to the "Set a New Password" *after* they have completed verifying their e-mail, so it's not even doing *that* step when you click `Continue`.

The first observer removes the `Continue` button from the first step.  This leaves the "Send Verification Code" button and the e-mail input in the UI.

The second observer hides the `Continue` button for the second step and disables the ability to alter the e-mail address after "Send Verification Code" is clicked.

The last observer causes the `Continue` button to be clicked for the user after the user's verification code has been confirmed valid, eliminating the need to click the `Continue` button.