# B2C custom policies - Remove email change step in azure b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I used this [documentation](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup) to split email verification and signup.

I would like to remove the third page in the email verification flow as you can see in the image from the page above. (It's the one with the 'Change email' button).

Is there a way to prevent email verification for a second time? Do I need to remove an orchestration to acheave it?

A question was asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69509093/adjust-email-verification-user-interface-in-azureb2c-custom-policies) link, I tried the same solution but it only hides the change email button, but not associated elements.

This is my Technical profile for emailVerification :

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerification">
          <DisplayName>Initiate Email Address Verification For Local Account</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

And this is my userjourney for combined signup and signin flow :

```
    <UserJourneys>
    <!--Forgot password-->
    <UserJourney Id="CustomSignUpSignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerification" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
  <SubJourneys>
    <!--Forgot password-->
    <SubJourney Id="PasswordReset" Type="Call">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <!-- Validate user's email address. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Collect and persist a new password. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </SubJourney>
  </SubJourneys>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

As per the answers you found, you must hide that button with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I resolved it by applying your solution suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708522/simplify-embeded-password-reset-azure-b2c-custom-policies?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft document is also suggesting to hide the button https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow#hide-the-change-email-button

Comment: I think this would more appropriatly have been a comment on the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72009387/7733418